# GitLab CI pipeline not triggered on commit (and commit not showing up in Activity feed)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-pages

I just started having a problem when I commit to my repo:

1. commit doesn't trigger CI pipeline, even though it should
2. commit doesn't show up in the Activity feed

I have a repo on GitLab, and have been using GitLab Pages to publish a static site when I push changes to the repo.

I haven't used it in a month, and today, for some reason, it is not triggering the pipeline as it usually does. I have not changed anything about my `.gitlab-ci.yml`, which consists of the following YAML:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir .public
    - cp -r path_to_my_rendered_site/* .public
    - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

It's not that the pipeline is failing, it's simply not being triggered at all.

If I look in **Repository > Commits**, I see that earlier commits triggered the pipeline, and deployed the site:

[image]

But for my commit today (and other ones I've tried since), there's nothing:

[image]

For the second, maybe related problem: I noticed as well that my recent commits do not show up in the **Project Information > Activity** feed.  Under All, I see all my older commits, but the ones today are not there.  I imagine this is related.

Comment: Now I checked back a few days later, and the commits have all triggered their pipelines like they should.  It must have simply been delayed (?).

Comment: Experiencing the exact same thing right now, is gitlab down from time to time without any notice? I also couldn't create a merge request through the UI (loading merge request forever).

Comment: I've noticed you can trigger a pipeline manually (you can for exemple select an existing tag). If I do this I get a pipeline that remains on the "created" state, but it never starts.

Comment: I never got to the bottom of this.  It happened once again, and when I waited a few hours, it had resolved itself.  I suppose it may simply be that the system is down intermittently, but doesn't report so.